# I am trying to click on option from react_select with selenium in python but I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, react-select

I am trying to click on option from react_select with selenium in python but I get  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

this is my function

```
  def click_on_react_select(self, react_option):
    locator = (By.ID, "InputTypeSearchListSearchBusinessSelectDistributor")
    self.driver.tools.wait_and_click(locator)

    for option in self.driver.tools.get_text_from_element(locator).split('\n'):
        if option == react_option:
            option.click()
    assert self.driver.tools.wait_for_element_and_get_attribute(locator, "value"
                                                                ) == react_option
```

Comment: `split('\n')` splits string to list of strings... and you iter through that list so `option` is a string

Comment: thank's for your help but I don't understand what else to do

Comment: you should get original `<select>` (instead of text) and use `send_key()` with `arrow down` to select on list and then `click()` it.